# Pass parameter to the function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I have a nodejs neo4j query in the below format. But it does not recognize the parameter "code" while calling the raw function.

```
const getCodes = ({ code }) =>
    QueryBuilder()
    .raw("MATCH (j:DETAILS) WHERE j.code = {code} RETURN j");
```

It does not recognize the input that I pass.

Any leads/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: which library are you using to connect to Neo4j?

Comment: @TomažBratanič: I use cypher-query-builder'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the code examples, havent seen an identical queryBuilder example, but the following example seems similar

```
query.raw('MATCH (:Event { date: $date }', { date: '2017-01-01' })
```

Seems you can add a secondary input, where you provide query parameters. I would try:

```
const getCodes = ({ code }) =>
    QueryBuilder()
    .raw("MATCH (j:DETAILS) WHERE j.code = {code} RETURN j", {"code":code});
```